# I want to add a weight dropdown on product grid like bigbasket

Tags: products, product-page, product-grid

[image]

I just want the code and the files which needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a configurable product based on a weight attribute that you'll have to add.

Once this is done you can create multiple simple products which will represent the weight declination of your configurable product.

Comment: so how to display it in product grid ?

Comment: on the frontend?

Comment: yes on the frontend